# How to change the contents between "{" and "}" using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

For example, we have a file like:

```
{abc}...{def}
```

How to append `123` at the end of every string inside the `{}` and meanwhile, remove the `{}`? The above would be changed to:

```
abc123...def123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this sed:

```
echo "$s"|sed 's/{\([^}]*\)}/\1123/g'
abc123...def123
```

Or using awk:

```
awk -v x=123 -F '[{}]' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i%2) printf $i, OFS; else printf $i x, OFS; print ""}'
abc123...def123
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sed capturing group

```
echo '{abc}...{def}' | sed 's/{\([^}]*\)}/\1123/g'
abc123...def123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/{//g; s/}/123/g'
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "{abc}...{def}"|sed 's/{//g; s/}/123/g' 
abc123...def123
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu awk`

```
echo '{abc}...{def}' | awk '{print gensub(/{([^}]*)}/,"\\1123","g")}'
abc123...def123
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;s/{\([^{}]*\)}/\1123/g;ta' file
```

or:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/{\([^{}]*\)}/\1123/g' -e 'ta' file
```